# SwiftUI - explain difference in EnvironmentObject vs ObservableObject behavior on data refresh in View

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am building an Instagram-like app and I have noticed that if a view uses an ObservableObject (viewModel.posts) to access data from Firestore, the view flickers when data is refreshed. e.g. if the like button is pressed or if a new post is added.

When a view accesses data from Firestore using an EnvironmentObject (session.posts), the updates occur smoothly without any flickering. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Here is the code for the ObservableObject:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class PostViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    init() {

        fetchPosts()
    }
    
    func fetchPosts() {

        COLLECTION_POSTS
            .order(by: "timeStamp", descending: true)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("Error fetching Request documents: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                self.posts.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

                for doc in documents {
                    let mappedDoc = Post(dictionary: doc.data())
                    self.posts.append((mappedDoc!))
                }
                return
            }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the EnvironmentObject:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class FirebaseSession: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts: [Post] = []
}

extension FirebaseSession {

    func listenerPosts() {
        
        COLLECTION_POSTS
            .order(by: "timeStamp", descending: true)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("Error fetching Request documents: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                self.posts.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                
                for doc in documents {
                    let mappedDoc = Post(dictionary: doc.data())
                    self.posts.append((mappedDoc!))
                }
                return
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use the ObservableObject in your view are you using it as @ObservedObject or @StateObject?

Comment: How did you manage to put `@Published` in the extension? Are you sure you didn't omit any important code?

Comment: @jnpdx, I am using an ObservedObject in the view, not a StateObject.

Comment: @pawello2222 - you are right, I have the published in the class FirebaseSession.

Comment: I think the reason for the refresh is because the view is getting initialized (redrawn) with any changes

Comment: I think you are aright, it seems that the view for ObservableObject is runnning `init()` everytime there is change, this would mean that the view is cleared and redrawn after a change is detected. I found these two articles explaining differences I hope they can help you understand [article1](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject) [article2](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/07/02/the-difference-between-stateobject-environmentobject-and-observedobject-in-swiftui/)

Comment: Solved: Using ObservedObject redraws the View, using StateObject solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Using ObservedObject redraws the View, using StateObject solved the issue